# Does isotropy depend on the location of the origin from where we see the medium?

Tags: symmetry

Let us say we have a charged non-conducting sphere having a spherically symmetrical charge density $\rho (r)$ that decreases as $r$.

Ignoring all other properties, If we positon ourselves in the *center* of the sphere, the medium will appear isotropic because of the spherical symmetry charge distribution. But if we were to change our position to somewhere else other than the origin, the medium would no longer appear isotropic.

So does the isotropy of a medium depend on where we view it from? And if we say a given material is isotropic, should we understand this as it being isotropic  with reference to some "special" point?

Comment: While what you describe is spherically symmetric, I would not call it isotropic. If a special origin is needed, your material is not isotropic.

Comment: @Jon Custer So in definitive, a material is isotropic when its properties are independent of the direction for *every* point in the material chosen as our reference for direction?

Comment: Yup, that summarizes it...

Comment: @Jon Custer Just to be sure, doesn't this definition imply every isotropic medium is homogeneous?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between homogeneous and isotropic material?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153008/what-is-difference-between-homogeneous-and-isotropic-material)